# Reset “Use Secure in Front End or Admin” in Database is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, https

I have carefully follow instruction to setup SSL in Front-end and Admin panel by using

**System -> Configuration -> Web -> Use Secure URLs in Frontend**

and

**System -> Configuration -> Web -> Use Secure URLs in Frontend**

to "**Yes**"

After that I can't access my Administrator Panel anymore, it always redirected to https.

I have tried to revert the config. But still no luck, I also have change database table : `core_config_data`. `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` to `0` and `web/secure/offloader_header` is SSL_OFFLOADED.

Also, remove cache and session data. Still no luck.

I using Magento 1.9 and Nginx.

I got it, it was the Magento cache problem, somehow it was cache inside the folder `/tmp/magento/var/cache` of my Linux (not Magento tmp folder). After I delete it, I can finally access my adminhtml using HTTP.

Comment: How many stores are there?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you one solution I dont know you have tried or not But you can try below solution

go to your mysql

fire this query  `SELECT * FROM mgnt_core_config_data WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url'`

and change your unsecure base url to your url without `https`, so it would be `http://your_base_url`

Try And let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I have tried to change the url to http, but still no luck

Comment: You using any cdn ? if yes then try to purge that cdn

Comment: I currently didnt use any cdn.

By the way, this problem also occurred in Front-end pages which has any textbox or input such as Login and Signup page.